StringParameter.fromSecureStringParameterAttributes works with String as well as SecureString
The documentation for fromSecureStringParameterAttributes says:

Imports a secure string parameter from the SSM parameter store.

Why is it that this function also works for Strings? Only SecureString is mentioned in the documentation.
I just found out I have been using this in AWS deployments with a String (not SecureString) from AWS SSM and it has not been throwing an Exception.
